# How to use Textwrap property without defining the width in windows phone development?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock

I am using a grid with single row. I have placed a single LongListSelector within that row. The ItemTemplate is as follows,

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--when we dont mention any of the height and width properties then control tries to first occupy the minimum height/width required and then it streches to the extent it is possible-->
    <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="0" x:Name="CLASS1">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="25,20" Background="#FF616464" Width="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="40" Margin="20,20" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

Now I know that if we don't mention the width,MaxWidth values in the XAML file or in the properties, the Textblock above will stretch itself to the width it really needs to fit in the text. If there still some more width remaining it will expand till that extent. However I want to wrap the text of the Textblock. At the same time I want to utilize all the width available for stretching the TextBlock. So basically I want that the Textblock to stretch itself using the maximum width available and if the Text within it is still longer then I want to wrap it. Is there any solution to achieve this. I can use text wrap by setting constant value for width. As I want to deploy this application on different models then can I make it generic? Is there anyway to use parent's width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to replace `StackPanel` with `Grid`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Margin="25,20" Background="#FF616464" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding title, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="40" Margin="20,20" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Result: 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Rejman What does Grid do that Stackpanel cant. When we mention width as 'Auto' it adjusts itself with the content length. So how does grid work here? Which one is ideal to use for LongListSelector? Stackpanel or Grid?

Comment: Grid stretches content to its boundaries. StackPanel can grow forever.

Comment: Thanks that was the difference i needed.

Answer (score 0):

try this property 
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"